# Why does this user(Manager) get this error when trying to submit for approval record created by other user?

Tags: approval-process

Why does Melanie (mgr to Caroline) get this error when trying to submit for approval record created by Caroline?[image]

where,

Melanie- Manager of Caroline.

Record- TS00000436 (owner- Caroline)

In approval process-

Initial submitter- Trunk Stock Request Owner so by default Caroline.
Assigned Approver- Melanie (Manager)

So while submitting why does melanie gets this error message?

Comment: This is just a warning message to prevent submissions by mistake and not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the standard Approval process confirmation message popup. There is no such way to get rid of that pop-up message with customization. Still, if you want to get rid of that popup then you have to write Apex trigger on Trunk Stock Request object or you can create a custom button and execute the approval process from the apex.